# How to get common elements of two lists, which are themselves lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of lists:

```
l1 = [[3,1],[1,2],[1,'a'],[1,4]]
l2 = [[3,1],[1,4],[1,5],[1,'a']]
```

and I want to get their intersection, i.e., `[[3,1],[1,4],[1,'a']]`. How can I do this?

Comment: Should duplicates be preserved?

Comment: @timgeb if you are referring to the order of elements within each sublist, yes.

Comment: @gill nope, but there shouldn't be any duplicates anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your clarification comments on the question, do it like this:

Convert one of the lists to a set (for the O(1) lookup time), then employ a list comprehension.

```
>>> l2_s = set(map(tuple, l2))
>>> [x for x in l1 if tuple(x) in l2_s]
[[3, 1], [1, 'a'], [1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = [[3,1],[1,2],[1,'a'],[1,4]]
l2 = [[3,1],[1,4],[1,5],[1,'a']]
intersection = []
for x in l1:
    if x in l2:
        intersection.append(x)
print (intersection)
```

Use for loop find same elements and append them into another list.

Output;

```
[[3, 1], [1, 'a'], [1, 4]]
>>>
```

**Or shorter way**, use list comprehensions;

```
l1 = [[3,1],[1,2],[1,'a'],[1,4]]
l2 = [[3,1],[1,4],[1,5],[1,'a']]

print ([x for x in l1 if x in l2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the inner elements will always be in the same order.

```
out = set(map(tuple, l1)).intersection(map(tuple, l2))
```

## Output

```
set([(1, 'a'), (3, 1), (1, 4)])
```

Note that the above returns a set of tuples, not lists.  But you can easily convert them back to lists if needed:

```
map(list, out)
```

Comment: This is a good answer if the lists can contain duplicates and when the order of the result does not matter and might be helpful for anyone who googles this question.